# t-rex Error: ERROR there is not enough huge-pages memory in your system

Tags: dpdk, huge-pages

I am using t-rex traffic generator and when I try to run using `sudo ./t-rex-64 -i --arp-refresh-period 30` it stops after giving the following error:

> ERROR there is not enough huge-pages memory in your system
> Cause: Cannot init nodes mbuf pool nodes-0

Now my initial understanding is that there isn't enough space left in the system but the result of `free -h` shows otherwise.

> ```
>           total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
> Mem:       62G        9.2G         49G        159M        4.2G         52G
> Swap:      31G        1.5M         31G
> ```

When I ran the t-rex command for the first time I found this warning message

> WARNING: tried to configure 2048 hugepages for socket 0, but result is: 536

Is it possible that at first attempt it allocated space for 536 hugepages and in order to work properly I need to first free those spaces and re-allocate hugepages again?

Any kind of help is highly appreciated.

**EDIT**
The result of `grep Huge /proc/meminfo` is:

```
AnonHugePages:   3686400 kB
HugePages_Total:    2048
HugePages_Free:     1536
HugePages_Rsvd:        0
HugePages_Surp:        0
Hugepagesize:       2048 kB
```

Comment: can you please update `what is result for grep Huge /proc/meminfo? if it less than 2048 you will need to configure 2048 2MB pages`. Are you using Single or dual NUMA socket platform. If it is DUAL either add double the required Huge page or add 2MB specific to NUMA.

Comment: @VipinVarghese I have added the hygepage info.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution, but don't have the correct explanation behind this solution. So if anyone can explain, it will be really helpful.

The working solution is to add `--astf` flag, so the whole command will look like

```
sudo ./t-rex-64 -i --astf --arp-refresh-period 30
```